# Analogue of "Solidify" modifier using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, solidify-modifier

I am trying to create a conical pipe of a certain thickness.

[image]

But the combination I use leaves the inner walls of the pipe unfilled.

[image]

I need an analogue of the "Solidify" modifiers using geometry nodes to solve this problem and, for example, create a cavity in a regular cube or sphere. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setup is good so far. What you need for the inner face is simply to join the original mesh before extrusion to the extruded one. Since the normals on the inside are facing in the wrong direction now, you need to also place a *Flip Faces* node after the *Curve to Mesh* before the *Join Geometry* node.

The problem with the *Extrude Mesh* node in GN is that there is no "Even Thickness" setting like in the *Solidify* modifier. So in some or more likely a lot of cases you will not get a similar result.

[image: solidify GN]

Comment: Too bad that various modifiers have not yet been translated into *Geometry Nodes*. However, there are positive developments in this direction (example: "Bevel Modifier").

Comment: You mean... _Bevel_ is in the latest version?

Comment: @RobinBetts I was wondering the same... I got 3.3.0 Beta and 3.4.0 Alpha but I didn't find it.

Comment: @quellenform Where can we find the _Bevel Modifier_ in GN? I'm really looking forward to that...

Comment: @RobinBetts ...I think it will take a few more versions, because there is still a lot to do here.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hans Goudey wrote in a post dated Thu, Jul 28, 18:42: *"There is already work underway for a new bevel implementation as a node."* [Link](https://developer.blender.org/T100042)

Comment: @quellenform Ah okay, that's nice to know.

Answer (score -1):

This is a strange scenario, but for a plane this worked.  It's two extrude meshes, one set to zero and the other to the "solidify" size.  [image]