# Geometry Node: Add Thickness to Meshline used for a Flower Petal

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I have been trying to add a thickness to my flower petal (see Fig. 1). A single petal is itself is defined as shown in the node viewer (see Fig. 2) in geometry nodes. I have tried 1) adding an "Extrude Mesh" node at different locations, 2) adding a solify modifier, 3) adding a radius but all without luck so far. If you have an idea or a solution please let me know.

Note that option 2. Solidify Modifier doesnt work well, because the flower consists various elements i.e., the petals, flower stem, flower inside etc. Adding a solidify modifier will for some reason extrude only parts of the entire flower.

[image: Fig 1: Single Flower Petal]

[image: Fig 2: Geometry Node of a single Flower Petal]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271732/analogue-of-solidify-modifier-using-geometry-nodes